# Calling a function inside a loop breaks it

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a function that loops an object from a MongoDB collection. It's all possible connections for some mail transportation posts. Once I get one connection, I want to immediately remove the inverse connection from the connections object, for example, postA=1 and postB=2, I want to remove postA=2 and postB=1 (`removeConnection` function does that).

I can't understand why it only returns one 'A' on the console when I try to run that function inside `calculateRoute`, and returns three 'A' (which is what it should) when I remove it. That function is somehow breaking the loop.

```
calculatedRoutes = calculateRoute(store.postid, client.postid, connections, []);

function calculateRoute(actualPost, finalPost, connections, routes) {
    for(i=0; i < connections.length; i++) {
        if(actualPost == connections[i].postA) {

            console.log('A');

            // If I remove this, the console shows A three times. If I keep this, only shows 1 time.
            connections = removeConnection(connections[i].postB, connections[i].postA, connections);
        }
    }

    return routes;
}

function removeConnection(postA, postB, connections) {
    for(i=0; i < connections.length; i++) {
        if(connections[i].postA == postA && connections[i].postB == postB) {
            delete connections[i];
            //break;
        }
    }

    return connections;
}
```

Comment: Your function changes the collection you are iterating over.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea but it does not affect the iteration. I even tried changing `connections` to `newConnections` with the return of the function but the same happens.

Comment: I agree with PM, but I think that can be fixed if you increment `i` only if you don't `removeConnection()`. Maybe.

Comment: I tried not iterating over (renamed and then removed the attribution), still breaks the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding `var` to `i=0` on each `for`. Can someone explain?

```
for(var i=0; i < connections.length; i++) {...
```

Comment: oh that's because without declaring `i`, it is assumed to be a global variable and so `removeConnection` would essentially be setting `window.i = 0` and incrementing it to `i = connections.length`. That would cause it to behave just like a break

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are modifying the collection that you are iterating over when you call`removeConnection`. I would venture to say that after the first loop, `connections.length` is less than your loop control variable, which would cause the loop to terminate. What are the contents of `connections` after the function call?

In general, directly modifying a collection you're iterating over is bad practice. A better option would be to project the collection into a new one that contains the values you want (using map,filter,etc). That way your not mutating anything.

Comment: you can also iterate over the collection in reverse order

Comment: @Nick There's many different Swift could solve the problem. The main bug in the current implementation though is that the collection is being directly modified by the "delete" statement in removeConnections

Comment: Hmm it appears using `delete` doesn't alter the length of the array 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5767335/1076471

Comment: However, deleting an item with `delete` will cause it to return `undefined` so `if(actualPost == connections[i].postA)` would really be `if(actualPost == undefined.postA)` which is an error since undefined can't have a property. I'd recommend checking your console output

Comment: @Nick Doh! Completey forgot about that! Again, of of the many reason I avoid the delete operator hehe

Comment: I understand all that, but as I mention in a comment from my question, I changed `connections = removeConnection(conn...` to `newConnections = removeConnection(conn...` and it still breaks the loop and the `connections` object isn't being modified.